# Losing text after a space setting the value in a new field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an odd issue when using Javascript to create a new field. I have button that, when clicked, will create two text fields. I give those text fields a string as a value. However, it is only working correctly if I give it a string with no spaces. If my string contains a space then it makes the value equal to the text before the space occurs.

```
function nameField() {
  $('#nameArea').html("<br/>First Name:<input type='text' id='fnField' value=" + $('#firstName').text() + ">Last Name:<input type='text' id='lnField' value=" + $('#lastName').text() + "></input><button id='bName' onclick='updateName(fnField.value, lnField.value)'>Save Changes</button>");
  $('#firstName').html("");
  $('#lastName').html(""); 
}
```

So for example, if the firstName value is `David E`, it is currently only putting `David` in the field as the value.  However, I have used alert and can confirm that `$('#firstName').text();` does contain the full `David E`.  How can I make sure that the text after the space doesn't get slashed out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is because you don't have any string delimiters around the `value`. Note the double quotes (`"`) around the values of the attributes in this example:

```js
$('#nameArea').html('<br/>First Name:<input type="text" id="fnField" value="' + $('#firstName').text() + '">Last Name:<input type="text" id="lnField" value="' + $('#lastName').text() + '"></input><button id="bName" onclick="updateName(fnField.value, lnField.value)">Save Changes</button>');
```

Alternatively you can avoid the string concatenation completely by using a Template Literal, but be aware this is unsupported in IE.

```js
$('#nameArea').html(`<br/>First Name:<input type="text" id="fnField" value="${$('#firstName').text()}">Last Name:<input type="text" id="lnField" value="${$('#lastName').text()}"></input><button id="bName" onclick="updateName(fnField.value, lnField.value)">Save Changes</button>`);
```

Finally, you can tidy this HTML further by removing the `onclick` attribute and using unobtrusive event handlers instead. You can use `data` attributes to contain the necessary metadata with the element.

Comment: Thank you! That was it.  I guess the quote right after the equals sign made it easy for me to miss.  I would have expected it to not work at all without the string delimiters.

Comment: @user3225440 HTML is pretty lenient in those cases (too lenient IMO :) ) if you don't have the quotes around the value, it will take the first word break as the end of the value - hence why your code originally cut off.

Answer (score 1):

This is a logical error caused by the lack of quotes around the value you give.

You set the html to `value=First Lastname` instead of `value='First Lastname'`. In the first case most browsers parse the string till the whitespace and therefor only the firstname shows up.

Try

```
$('#nameArea').html("<br/>First Name:<input type='text' id='fnField' value='" + $('#firstName').text() + "'>Last Name:<input type='text' id='lnField' value='" + $('#lastName').text() + "'></input><button id='bName' onclick='updateName(fnField.value, lnField.value)'>Save Changes</button>");
```